# electron + react + redux communication between two windows freezes PC?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying to update state in another window depedning on state changes in the first window but ipc communcation doesn't work as expected for me.

In my first window, I have:

```
onStatsSelect(event, menuItem, index) {
    const selectedStatsCopy = this.state.selectedStats.slice();
    const itemIndex = selectedStatsCopy.indexOf(menuItem.props.primaryText);
    if (itemIndex > -1) {
      delete selectedStatsCopy[itemIndex];
    } else {
      selectedStatsCopy[index] = menuItem.props.primaryText;
    }

    // Update state
    this.setState({ selectedStats: selectedStatsCopy });

    // Notify worker window of change
    if (!(this.props.isReport)) {
      console.log('in renderer main window');
      ipcRenderer.send("updateSelectedStatsMain", event, selectedStatsCopy);
    }
  }
```

This is a callback for updating selectedStats state. It will also notify worker window of this update as seen in the last lines. `if (!(this.props.isReport))` This is an important check since both windows share the same component and so I use property `isReport` to distinguish between the two.

In my main process, I have:

```
  // Selected Stats have changed in main window
  ipcMain.on('updateSelectedStatsMain', (event, selectedStatsCopy) => {
    console.log('in main');
    // Send to worker window
    workerWindow.webContents.send('updateSelectedStatsRen', event, selectedStatsCopy);
  });
```

This code will communicate back to worker window with the new state `selectedStatsCopy`.

In my `comoponentDidMount`, I have:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Register listening to message in case this is the worker window
    if (this.props.isReport) {
      console.log('in renderer worker window');
      ipcRenderer.on("updateSelectedStatsRen", (event, selectedStatsCopy) => {
        console.log('in renderer worker window event');
        this.setState({ selectedStats: selectedStatsCopy });
      });
    }
  }
```

This is supposed to work but electron hangs at line `ipcRenderer.send("updateSelectedStatsMain", event, selectedStatsCopy);` making main window hangs for a while and it continues using resources until PC freezes.

What is the problem here?

Comment: There's probably a loop somewhere, for example you try to setState in the render method, which causes a re-render loop. Look out for something like that.

Comment: I think I figured out. The parameters coming to the methods are not what I'm expecting.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. Still can't solve this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the error which I still don't know why it did freeze electron.

Basically I was doing

`ipcRenderer.send("updateSelectedStatsMain", event, selectedStatsCopy);`

This make absolutely no sense since I'm passing the event as a parameter. I don't even have an event variable to pass.

Updating this:

`ipcRenderer.send("updateSelectedStatsMain",event, selectedStatsCopy);`

to  this:

`ipcRenderer.send("updateSelectedStatsMain", selectedStatsCopy);`

and this:

`workerWindow.webContents.send('updateSelectedStatsRen', event, selectedStatsCopy);`

to this:

`workerWindow.webContents.send('updateSelectedStatsRen', selectedStatsCopy);`

fxied the issue for me.